# CSS Background not displaying

Tags: php, html, css

I'm getting back into web design after a several year break, so a lot of the tips and tricks that I used on a regular basis before just don't seem to be working.  I'm designing a guild website for my World of Warcraft guild for some practice, but I'm having issues getting the div background images to show up properly on the page.

The page consists of a container DIV, a header DIV, a Menu DIV, and a three column layout, followed of course by a footer div.  Above the menu I have a little artistic background I'm susing, and I managed to get that one to show up; however, I can't get the proper image to show up above the left or right bars properly.  I've searched the net a ton, and am still dumbfounded as to what I'm doing wrong.  Here is a screen shot of what I sort of want the layout to look like: http://s19.postimage.org/7svzmuaf7/Layout_V2.jpg

Currently, this is what I'm getting when you visit the website in any major browser: http://cirquedufreak.net78.net/

There is obviously some differences in the two, as one is just a jpg, and the other is a css/html combo, and that I'm aware of.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Source Code:

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("wowarmoryapi/BattlenetArmory.class.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home - Cirque du Freak of Vashj</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Roster</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">LEFTBAR</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="gmod">
            <h1>Important Message</h1>
            <p>This is where any "breaking news" or important information that you want to give to the players will be displayed.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbar">
        <p>For an invitation, contact one of the following players in game:</p>
        <?php

        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">&copy;2012 Cirque du Freak Guild of Vashj; All Rights Reserved.<br />World of Warcraft and related images and materials are &copy; Blizzard Entertainment.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

layout.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* CSS LAYOUT BEGIN */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FC3;
    text-align: center;
}
div#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
}
div#header {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 147px;
    background: url(images/v2_header.png);
}
div#menu {
    width:1024px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    background: url(images/v2_menuBG.png);
}
div#leftbar {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 525px;
    min-heigh: 150px;
    background-image: url(images/v2_barBG.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: top left;
}
div#content {
    float: left;
    width: 684px;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 525px;
}
div#rightbar {
    float: right;
    width: 170px;
    height: 525px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-image: url(images/v2_barBG.png) no-repeat;
}
div#footer {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
/* CSS LAYOUT END */

/* CSS MENU BEGIN */
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 1024px;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    width: 140px;
    color: #FF0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
#menu ul li a:visited {
    color: #FF0;
}
#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li .current {
    color: #F00;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: transparent;
}
/* CSS MENU END */

/* LEFT BAR CSS BEGIN */

/* LEFT BAR CSS END */

/* CONTENT BOX CSS BEGIN */
#content div#gmod {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    border: #FFF 3px solid;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #FFF;
    overflow-style: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
#content div#gmod h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #F00;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 0px 5px;
/* CONTENT BOX CSS END */

/* RIGHT BAR CSS BEGIN */

/* RIGHT BAR CSS END */

/* FOOTER CSS BEGIN */
#footer {
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
}
/* FOOTER CSS END */
```

Thank you very much for taking the time to assist me with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use

```
background-image: url(images/v2_barBG.png) no-repeat;
```

but

```
background: url(images/v2_barBG.png) no-repeat;
```

Comment: I thought that I had tried that answer before, but I guess not.  Thank you very much for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

`background-image: url(images/v2_barBG.png) no-repeat;` should be `background-image: url(images/v2_barBG.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 1):

`background-image: url(images/v2_barBG.png) no-repeat;` <-- no-repeat should be declared seperatly like this: `background-repeat: no-repeat;`